# X-Axis out of whack. Print head crashing into bed during auto home

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, bltouch, x-axis, print-axis-offset

I have been able to print for almost a year, then it began to fail.
When I select Auto level from the LCD Screen, the print head moves to the front left, hovers the probe in the air, which causes the print head to crash into the bed while the (blue light is on) probe searches for the bed. Since the print head is too far to the left, the BLTouch probe can never find the bed and crashes the nozzle instead.

My setup:

- Ender 3 Pro,
- TH3D EZBoard Lite V1.2,
- BLTouch Probe,
- Marlin firmware,
- Glass bed.

When I power on, and set 'Auto Home', it goes to 117,117,5 after every tutorial and video I watch on Z-Offset setting.
I reset the EEPROM, Level the bed and save settings during each X-Offset attempt.

I am only using the knob on printer's console for the settings. I have disconnected OctoPrint.

I made my last successful print over a year ago, as regardless of the video I watch, or the website tutorial I follow, I always get the 117,117,5 setting, which looks ok, but always crashes on Auto level.
My Firmware is compiled using the TH3D website for this purpose when using their boards.

Comment: What do you mean by this '117,117,5'?
What are your **Probe Offset** values? You can find these values under Advanced settings in your printer's display.

Comment: When did the problem start? All of a sudden, or after a firmware update or else?

Comment: When I select Autohome, the print head moves to 117,117,5 (x,y,z axis reading on the LCD screen @ info page)
I no longer remember what caused the problem the first time, It's been well over a year since I was able to print.